# Finding the time derivative of intensity at the moment a particle passes through a point

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image: Problem + proposed solution attached.]

I'm unsure as to whether I set up the problem correctly.  I'm also unsure about whether I was supposed to plug in t= 0 at the very end, considering the particle is at (1,1) when t= 0.  Any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are perfectly correct in setting $t=0$ at the end, since that's the instant at which you would like to evaluate the derivative.

To verify, in Mathematica the problem can be solved as follows:

```
f[t_] := {1 + 2 t^2, Cos[\[Pi] t]};
U[x_, y_] := Cosh[x y]/(1 + x^2 + y^2);
D[U @@ f[t], t] /. t -> 0
```

which produces

```
0
```

confirming your original answer.